# how to execute notepad through HTML in onClick function....without pop-up blocker

Tags: javascript, html, excel

i want to execute notepad application through HTML button ...in internet explorer...

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

    function run() 
    {
    WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
    WshShell.Run("c:/windows/system32/notepad.exe", 1, false);
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" Click="run()">click</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well modern IE has activex locked down pretty tightly, did you make sure your page is in a zone where it is enabled?

Comment: We know what you are asking, but please phrase this into a question.

Comment: there is no `Click` event. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . This is a question and answer site and *"I want"* is not  question nor does it explain a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function runProgram()
        {
            var shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");                 
            var appWinMerge = "\"C:\\Program Files\\WinMerge\\WinMergeU.exe\" /e /s /u /wl /wr /maximize";
            var fileLeft = "\"D:\\Path\\to\\your\\file\"";
            var fileRight= "\"D:\\Path\\to\\your\\file2\"";
            shell.Run(appWinMerge + " " + fileLeft + " " + fileRight);
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <a href="javascript:runProgram()">Run program</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Works only with javascript and ActiveX activated.